# How to detect a program and shut it down

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scp

So, I have been working on a project for class, and I have half of it down, but the second half I have been googling and am unsure how to go about it. Here is the question: You suspect that there is a "bad" program (called “badprog” that launches at odd times on your server and does nefarious things such as logging onto a remote machine via ssh/sftp and copying files off of your server.  A) Write a script that does this (you need not schedule it, just run it in the background).  B) Next, write a script to detect “badprog", and shut it down.

I have finished part A (pretty much just using the scp command), but I am unsure how to do part B. any help would be appreciated! (I am using Linux Mint)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for whether a process is running `pgrep` is probably your friend, and `pkill` as well.  You can also look at the `ps` command and it's myriad options.

`pgrep badprog` will give you the PID of any processes with the executable `badprog`

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup a PID for a process using `pgrep badprog` and you could shut it down using e.g.:

```
for pid in `pgrep badprog`; do
    kill -9 $pid
done
```

This will loop over every PID `pgrep` gives you and will send the signal `SIGTERM` (shutdown immediately) to the command.

Comment: You could also do `pkill -9 badprog` for that

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complicated question.  Can you assume that you would know the name of the "bad program"?  If not, then you will need to identify all "bad" behaviors and create a function to test for them.  Each function would probably use a different low-level command, like "ps -ef" for processes, and netstat for network connection.